# French equivalent of the adjective "astringent"

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

I'm looking for the French equivalent of the adjective "astringent" in this precise sense:

> Causing a dry or puckering mouthfeel; characteristic of foods with high tannin content, such as certain kinds of berries and citrus fruits.

from [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/astringent#Adjective).

**EDIT**:

I am aware that the French counterpart *astringent* exists as well. But the [wiktionary entry](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/astringent) and the [one of TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/astringent) categorize this word as *Médecine* (not sure whether it's colloquial or not). The latter even says that is just "amer" which is not accurate in my viewpoint. [The definition of the Larousse](http://%20larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/astringent/5991) is what I'm looking for, but seems to be restrained to wine. However, [tea](https://www.japanesegreenteain.com/blogs/green-tea-and-health/what-does-astringency-mean-for-tea-drinking) or even *kaki* can be astringent too (see the last example of the [wiktionary entry](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/astringent)):

> Les kakis **astringents** doivent être mangés à surmaturité, à moins qu’ils ne soient traités artificiellement.
>
> — (Michel Chauvet, Encyclopédie des plantes alimentaires, Belin, 2018, page 256)

So rephrasing the question, do French-speaking people tend to say *astringent* or they simply say *amer*?

**SIDE NOTE**:

This question comes from the observation that in the [East Asian cultural sphere](http://East%20Asian%20cultural%20sphere), there is a colloquial way to express astringency that any child would understand. It's simply the sinograph 澀(traditional)/涩(simplified)/渋(kanji). Maybe in the Far East, there are much more occasions to express this taste (tea, fruits, [Chinese herbology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_herbology) etc.)

Comment: The adjective "astringent" actually exists in French! It seems to mean the same because we use it for certain wines containing a lot of tannins https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/astringent/5991

Comment: In the South Asian cultural sphere, astringency is one of the [six basic tastes](https://www.banyanbotanicals.com/info/ayurvedic-living/living-ayurveda/diet/six-tastes/). And in this context, the French word used is [*astringent*](http://www.ayurvedarevolution.com/les-6-saveurs-et-lalimentation/#:~:text=En%20Ayurv%C3%A9da%2C%20%C2%AB%20rasa%20%C2%BB%20signifie,%2C%20piquant%2C%20amer%20et%20astringent.) or [*âpre*](https://www.brin-d-herbe.fr/PBCPPlayer.asp?ID=1952993)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great difference between "amer" and "astringent".

- [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/amer) **amer** Âpre et souvent désagréable au goût, comme la saveur que procurent le quinquina, la gentiane ou le fiel de certains animaux.
- [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acerbe) **acerbe** [Surtout en parlant de produits naturels, en partic. de fruits non encore mûrs ou de leur saveur] Aigre et âpre au goût :
- [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/astringent) **astringent** MÉD. [En parlant de médicaments] Qui a la propriété de resserrer les tissus
  − P. ext. [En parlant de substances, de plantes, de leur odeur, de leur goût] Amer
- [TLFi](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/42824/french-equivalent-of-the-adjective-astringent) **styptique** MÉD., PHARM. Qui possède des propriétés astringentes et hémostatiques. Plante astringente et styptique (Ac.).

(*"Styptique" is sometimes used synonymously with "astringent" but that seems to be much less than precise usage.*)

"Astringent" is not colloquial, it is a rare word. A current term is "amer" (not colloquial either) but if "astringent" is sometimes used in a literary register to say "amer", this latter term does not imply at all astringency and is the only current term to refer to bitterness. As very few people know the adjective "astringent" they might for want of a better expression use the term "amer" in speaking of an astringent effect on taste organs.
A less current term is "acerbe" and that is used for a taste that would in English be called tart or sour.

Taste called "acerbe", if considered in  a substantial degree, is typical of the taste of the following things: [uncooked  quince](https://www.thespruceeats.com/quirky-yet-queenly-quince-2215671) ([cooked] [Quinces are appreciated for their intense aroma, flavour, and tartness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quince)), sap from unripe figs (fig milk), certain kakis.
In pharmacology are considered  four pairs in oposition : "lourd et léger" , "onctueux et âpre" (onctuosity and rugosity) , "froid et chaud" , "émoussé et incisif". It is this definition of "âpre" that is applicable in the definition of "acerbe"; "onctuosity" is sensation uniquely revealed by the sense of touch and so according to the logic in this pharmacist's standard "âpre" must have to do with the sense of touch; as said in this [article](https://www.lemonde.fr/m-styles/article/2019/08/02/toutes-les-nuances-de-l-astringence_5495982_4497319.html),
"[l]’astringence est plus une sensation qu’une saveur" et "[«] saveur âpre et astringente [» signifie «] acerbe, âpre, austère [»]". Therefore, on  occasions when an astringency is recognized people will more likely speak of "acerbité" (acerbe). Only rarely and inappropriately will the word "amer" be used. As can be seen in many articles the word "astringent" is also used although much less.

**Addition of a few references showing that although the word "acerbe" is enormously used nowadays in a figurative sense and although the on line Larousse dictionary doesn't mention the literal sense any more, it is a word which while much less common than in the past, is still in use in the fields of vine growing (enology), arboriculture (fruit trees) and cooking.** (*The reading of the pieces of text collected is instructive in the way of acquiring a better picture of the meanings of the words that have been discussed.*)

1973 [Melanges de Philologie Et D'histoire](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Gd8S8vDYgeoC&pg=PA149&dq=%22acerbe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP0qXarb3rAhUCD2MBHRhwB-w4ZBDoATAGegQIIRAC#v=onepage&q=%22acerbe%22&f=false) La plupart des lexiques de la langue française, depuis quatre siècles, donnent la poire d'angoisse comme un fruit âpre ou acerbe et en rattachent l'appellation au nom commun d'angoisse *.

1973 [Revue de L'Occident Musulman Et de la Méditerranée](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PkosAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22acerbe%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22acerbe%22) Toutefois , son affirmation que l ' acerbe provient du chaud et du sec est une erreur , à mon avis ; car l ' acerbe provient à coup sûr du froid et du sec . Quant à la viscosité ( luzûja ) , la puanteur ( natn ) la crasse ( dusûma ) et le goût des choses

2003 [Revue suisse de viticulture, arboriculture, horticulture](https://books.google.fr/books?id=PkosAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22acerbe%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22acerbe%22) Fruits de la variété Goldrich utilisés pour la prédiction des teneurs en matières solubles , de la fermeté de la chair et des extraits secs . Caractéristiques des stades de maturité , de gauche à droite : « récolte anticipée ( = acerbe ) » , « récolte

1983 [La description des champignons supérieurs: Basidiomycètes](https://books.google.fr/books?id=CcHItttQhroC&dq=%22acerbe%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22acerbe%22) Acerbe . – Il y a quelque humiliation à devoir constater la difficulté de fournir une définition sûre d ' un mot aussi usité . ... âcre , aigre , trois mots exprimant trois notions largement différentes , différentes entre elles et différentes de acerbe .

1970 [Savants du Monde Entier - Volume 39](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ssM4AQAAIAAJ&q=%22acerbe%22&dq=%22acerbe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjP0qXarb3rAhUCD2MBHRhwB-w4ZBDoATBaegQIERAC) S'il arrive qu'une substance chaude soit en même temps acerbe, une autre substance chaude insipide, une autre perturbatrice (et il y a une foule de substances chaudes qui ont beaucoup d'autres qualités opposées), il faudra bien donner la ...

1939 (https://books.google.fr/books?id=IvxJAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22acerbe%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22acerbe%22) Mélange acerbe, acide ; — 1605 : vin de bon goût ; —-8745 : corsé, très bon ; — 8365 : vin excellent ; -- 5455 : un peu acerbe, mais vin de bonne qualité. « Vins de Villefranche. — Vin rouge 6905 : très bon, acerbe ;

2010 [Le Corps humain](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3k3IBgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q=acerbe&f=false) Isolément, le goût reconnaît si un corps est salé ou sucré, acide, astringent, acerbe, douceâtre, etc. ; mais quand nos aliments n'éveillent pas chez nous d'autres sensations, nous sommes presque tentés, malgré toute leur saveur, de les ...

1945 [Les pruniers sauvages & cultivés](https://books.google.fr/books?id=H9c0AQAAIAAJ&q=%22acerbe%22&dq=%22acerbe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixvJC2tr3rAhWrAGMBHSZ3C_I4kAMQ6AEwFnoECEAQAg) avant le feuillage , sont assez grandes : pétales concaves , à anthères de ton rouge orangé ; le fruit est une drupe noirâtre , acerbe , de forme sphérique ;

2001 [Vignes, vins du Pays d'Oc](https://books.google.fr/books?id=p3ffAAAAMAAJ&q=%22acerbe%22&dq=%22acerbe%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixvJC2tr3rAhWrAGMBHSZ3C_I4kAMQ6AEwInoECE8QAg) spre , isprós : Acerbe , âpre , astringent . Var . gispre . V . aspre , vispre • Acerbe , se dit d ' un vin rendu âpre et vert par un fort excès de tanin et d ' acidité . Défaut très grave ( Gv ) . Isprejar : Etre acerbe , avoir de l ' âpreté

1922 [La nature: revue des sciences et de leurs applications aux arts et à l'industrie](https://books.google.fr/books?id=l0NGAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22acerbe%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22acerbe%22) On perçoit, par exemple, dans de rares cas, le goût des amandes (Tricholome-Panæole, Croquette-des-sapinières); des noisettes (Russuleagréable, Russule-rosée, Russule-jolie, - à saveur de noisettes un peu acerbe, - Bolet-châtain);

1929 [Arboriculture fruitière](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LDU-AQAAMAAJ&dq=%22acerbe%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22acerbe%22)  Le Pommier acerbe ( Malus acerba . Mérat ) . Rameaux grêles , plus épineux ; feuilles plus petites , glabres d'un vert clair , assez longuement pétiolées ; sleurs plus petites , rosées ; fruit petit , très acerbe . Le premier est considéré comme le ..

[wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/acerbe) 1. Qui est d’un goût aigre et âpre.
2. (Œnologie) Se dit d’un vin acide, dur et âpre.

[internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/acerbe/)
Sens 1
Cruel, méchant en parlant des propos ou des écrits de quelqu'un au sujet de quelqu'un d'autre ou de quelque chose.
Exemple : L'appréciation du professeur était si acerbe que l'élève en a pleuré.
Synonymes : acide, piquant, dur, incisif, vif, mordant, aigre, blessant
Traduction anglais : acerbic
Sens 2
Viticulture
Apre, à propos d'un vin au goût trop acide et trop dur.
Sens 3
Cuisine
Relatif à un goût aigre en cuisine.

internaute (https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/acerbe/)

Le monde Qui est d’un goût âpre, se dit dun vin acide, dur et âpre. - (note) Goût mordant souvent lié à une note végétale (macération de rafles vertes en vinification rouge), vendange peu mûre. - Le vin comme lamour, Lamour comme le vin, Quils soient impérissables, Quils soient sans lendemain, Quils soient bourrus, tranquilles, Acerbes ou élégants,Je suis sûre quil ne faut pas Mettre deau dedans. (Juliette Noureddine; « Petite messe solennelle » -2008) https://dicocitations.lemonde.fr/dico-mot-definition/1744/acerbe.php

[Savoir.fr](https://dictionnaire.savoir.fr/definition-acerbe/) adj. Apre et acide au goût. Les fruits verts sont acerbes. Agressif et mordant. Observations acerbes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Does the word *acerbe* imply a certain acidity? If so, isn't *âpre* a better candidate?

Comment: @FirminMartin 1/ It does also.2/ No, I don't believe so: (TLFi)  **A**  [En parlant d'une chose qui affecte les sens] Dont les inégalités produisent une impression peu agréable.
1. [Vue ou toucher] Des rochers âpres; un climat, un vent âpre **B** 2. [En parlant de ce qui affecte les autres sens : goût, odorat, ouïe] Qui produit une impression de rudesse. Un fruit, un parfum, un son âpre

Comment: *Acerbe* is no more used to mean astringent since one hundred years or something. It is only used figuratively nowadays: *une critique acerbe*, *des propos acerbes*, *une réponse acerbe* and so on. @FirminMartin Beware that almost nobody knows that outdated meaning.

Comment: What is certain is that those terminologies (*astringence*, *acerbe* and *âpre*) are still used in Oenology. (see [lexique des vins de Bourgogne](https://www.vins-bourgogne.fr/glossaire/acerbe,2530,9410.html?&args=Y29tcF9pZD0xNTU5JmFjdGlvbj12aWV3R2xvc3NhaXJlJmlkPSZtb3Q9NXw%3D)) @jlliagre Do you have a more colloquial word in mind? (consider to write your own answer).

Answer (score 3):

***Âpre*** is likely what I would use to describe that feeling. My second choice would be ***rugueux*** (rough). *Amer* is a different thing, *astringent* is far too formal, *acerbe* is only used figuratively nowadays and nobody would understand *styptique*.

Beware that while *acerbe* might be found in specialized jargon with the meaning you expect (the TLFi says *Au propre, **didactique***), almost nobody would understand it that way in a conversation, even less a child.

The translator of this book rightly chose *âpre*:

https://www.courrierinternational.com/article/2009/10/21/zoya-pirzad-laureate-2009-avec-le-gout-apre-des-kakis

Note that *âpre* is not really colloquial but at least it would be understood.

Comment: That confirms my thoughts, thanks.